# How to write complex SQL query for my given data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**How to write a complex SQL Query?**

Below information is the old data of users working on different services with service status and last change date on particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.
All users are working on multiple services where some of the services are still active for a particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.

**Requirements in words:**

I require to select all columns when the Service of the user is inactive and only record on that particular Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user.

As earlier mentioned that a user can have multiple services on a Service_Area and Service_Sector combined. In case if there are more than one services on Service_Area and Service_Sector for the user, then we need to select the record that was last changed if all the services are inactive (I mean, when there is a record in between whose service status is active, then we cant select any user data from that Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user).

**Scenarios:**

***Case 1:***
When there are 5-services, all of them are inactive then, we need to select the last changed record.

***Case 2:***
When there is at least one service with active status among 5-services then, we cant select that user data from that particular Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user.

***Case 3***
When there is only one service on that Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user, it's inactive then, the record will also get selected.

**About Table:**

Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector, Service will always make a unique combination. And there may be many services on this combination Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector.

Please find the sample table below with the result table (display expected output).

**Sample Table:**

| Loc_Code | User_Id | Service_Area | Service_Sector | Service | Status | Last_Changed |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **101** | **1001** | **C** | **1** | **PAINT** | **INACTIVE** | **11/28/2020** |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | WOOD | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | CLEANING | ACTIVE | 11/23/2020 |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | PEST | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |  |
| **101** | **1002** | **A** | **2** | **LIGHT** | **INACTIVE** | **12/7/2020** | ` |
| 101 | 1002 | B | 2 | AC | INACTIVE | 11/28/2020 |  |
| **101** | **1002** | **B** | **2** | **HEATER** | **INACTIVE** | **11/30/2020** |  |

**Result Table:**

Total 3-records are selected.

1. The first record is selected as the user was working on a single inactive service on a particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.
2. The second record is selected because Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector combination has only one service on it, which is inactive.
3. The third record selected because Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector combination list 2-inactive services, selected the service which was last changed.

| Loc_Code | User_Id | Service_Area | Service_Sector | Service | Status | Last_Changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1001 | c | 1 | PAINT | INACTIVE | 11/28/2020 |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 2 | LIGHT | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |
| 101 | 1002 | B | 2 | HEATER | INACTIVE | 11/30/2020 |

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Don't post links to images of table data.  Edit the question and put the sample data in there.  Also, what have you attempted?  You need to show a bit of effort here if you expect help.  thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - OP has not shown any attempts as solving the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to follow your logic, and I can't. 
Please post your tables as text, ideally as a dbfiddle. Please make the selection criteria more obvious - "all records whose service status is inactive" makes sense, but I don't understand the "twists"

Comment: yeah , what you explained doesn't support  what you showed as desired output

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want ,you can use `cte` and `window function` to achieve that:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * 
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LOC_N, U_NUM, SRV_AREA, SRV_SEC ORDER BY CHG_DATE desc)  AS _rank
        FROM yourtablename
    )

SELECT 
   LOC_N, U_NUM, SRV_AREA, SRV_SEC, SRV, STATUS, CHG_DATE 
FROM cte
WHERE 
   cte.STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
   AND cte._rank = 1
```

if you don't need to show SRV column , that query will be as simple as below :

```
SELECT
    LOC_N
    , U_NUM
    , SRV_AREA
    , SRV_SEC
    , STATUS
    , MAX(CHG_DATE) as CHG_DATE
FROM
    yourtablename
WHERE
    STATUS = 'INACTIVE'
GROUP BY
    LOC_N
    , U_NUM
    , SRV_AREA
    , SRV_SEC
    , STATUS;
```